# FFmpeg libswresample linker error

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, linker

I'm trying to set-up a function, using the ffmpeg c api, to re-sample a stream (AVStream format) to fixed (1channel - u8 sample) format.

I'm using ffmpeg libswresample library, but when I try to compile, I get a linker error that is strictly connected to swresample functions.

Let me post the code:

```
double *resample8(AVFrame *frame, int size, AVCodec* codec){

    /* initialization of the output array */
    double *out = new double[size];

    /* create resampling context */
    struct SwrContext *resampleContext;
    resampleContext = swr_alloc();
    if (!resampleContext) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate resampler context\n");
    return NULL;
    }

    /* set options */
    av_opt_set_int(resampleContext, "in_channel_layout", *(codec->channel_layouts), 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(resampleContext, "in_sample_fmt", *(codec->sample_fmts), 0);

    av_opt_set_int(resampleContext, "out_channel_layout", AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(resampleContext, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8, 0);

    /* initialize the resampling context */
    if (swr_init(resampleContext) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the resampling context\n");
    return NULL;
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Here is the inclusion:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif // __cplusplus
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
    #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
    #include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end extern "C".
#endif // __cplusplus
```

And here is the error I get, compiling with netbeans, g++
(additional g++ commands: -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample -lfftw3 -lm)

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync"
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audiosync
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync"
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audiosync build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/dataReader.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/tansforms.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/tognuplot.o  -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswresample -lfftw3 -lm
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/dataReader.o: nella funzione "resample8(AVFrame*, int, AVCodec*)":
/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync/dataReader.cpp:285: riferimento non definito a "av_opt_set_sample_fmt"
/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync/dataReader.cpp:288: riferimento non definito a "av_opt_set_sample_fmt"
/usr/local/lib/libswresample.so: riferimento non definito a "av_calloc@LIBAVUTIL_54"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:65: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audiosync" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/audiosync] Errore 1
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync"
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo ".build-conf" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/davide/Documenti/Tesi/audiosync-fin/audiosync"
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo ".build-impl" non riuscito
make: *** [.build-impl] Errore 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 5s)
```

here is the linker configuration [linker config](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2l6FPXN1f-EaEJfNmV2cjVUemM/view?usp=sharing)

I searched for any clue about the linker error, and I found that it could be caused by multiple versions of ffmpeg installed. I removed ubuntu (I'm using 15.04) base installation of ffmpeg and installed ffmpeg 2.7.2 from the tar downloaded by ffmpeg.org

I can't seem to find a solution at the moment, can anyone help?

Comment: What's your exact linker command line? Order of specified libraries matters, unless you place them into a group.

Comment: [linker configuration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2l6FPXN1f-EaEJfNmV2cjVUemM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add such information in your question.

Comment: No sure if you can configure this from your IDE, but as mentioned GCC supports the `-Wl,--start-group` `-Wl,--end-group` options, that you can surround the libraries list to solve problems appearing with their order.

Comment: As i've said, I use netbeans IDE, and g++ to compile, as it is a c++ application.

Answer (score -1):

I think the linking order matters 
refer this question
[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Try this order

```
libavdevice libavformat libavfilter libavcodec libwscale libavutil libswresample libswscale libpostproc libavresample
```